# Mac OS X Finder: show just file details

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, customization

The Finder in column view shows a preview of the file, then information listed below it. The preview (which has no value to me) takes up most of the available space and the file information I want to see is hidden.

All I want to see is the size, creation and modification dates. I would also like to get rid of the "more" section, which is useless and just takes up space.

In the image below, the preview takes up most of the space, the "more" section takes up nearly 1/4 of the space and of the 3 things I want to see most, only the size is available. The name and filetype is already displayed on the column to the left, it's pointless to repeat it under the preview.

[image: Preview image]

I know I could switch to the list view, but I've used the column view forever (since 1990) and it **was** extremely useful, now it's just a daily annoyance. I also don't want to have to navigate to directory using one view, then switch views to select a file, then go back to column view to navigate, etc.

I'm not a fan of Windows, but I find I can configure Windows Explorer to suit me much better than the Mac OS Finder as I can get rid of the preview and show just the information I want.

Is there any way to do that in the Finder?

Answer (score 2):

In Finder, select View → Preview options. This displays a dialog.

[image: Preview Options dialog]

Turning off all options except the couple that I want means I now have the view I want.

[image]

Comment: Yeah - it took me *forever* to find & get rid of the "Show Quick Actions", which was nothing more than a useless box hiding half the info :\